# Throw exception from spring controller which producces xml MediaType

Tags: spring, exception

I have the the following controller with one RequestMapping which produces an xml MediaType.

```
 @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class ArticleResource {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/xml/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getXml(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id,
                                              final HttpServletRequest request,
                                              final HttpServletResponse response) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(path + id + ".xml");

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                throw new BadRequestException("No such xml exists");
            }
            try {
                return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream), HttpStatus.OK);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

The BadRequestException implementation is the following:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException {

    public BadRequestException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

It works fine when the xml exists, but when the xml cannot be found I have a 406 error code. I suppose the problem occurs because it expects a xml media type and instead a RuntimeException is returned. How can I tackle with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an `Accept:` header in your HTTP request? Your error handler will just return an HTTP error code (response status) so it causes a 406 `Not Acceptable` on the client side if the client expects XML.
If this is the case you can return an XML response entity from the error handler and update your signature to reflect that it produces XML. Or you can try removing the `Accepts` from your request.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by returning the following:

```
String returnString = "XML file don't exists";
return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(IOUtils.toByteArray(
                        new ByteArrayInputStream(returnString.getBytes())), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```